# laravel 5 getting average from relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to get just Average via Relationships

what I am doing is :

```
$user_detail=Users::withCount('followers')->withCount('followings')->withCount('posts')->with('ratings')->with('posts')->where('user_id',$user_id)->get();

public function ratings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Reviews','review_user_id','user_id')->selectRaw('review_user_id, avg(rate) AS avg')->groupBy('review_user_id');
}
```

Now this is working, and what I am getting is :

```
"followers_count": 0,
"followings_count": 1,
"posts_count": 1,
"ratings": [
      {
        "review_user_id": "2c61d7a0-7d05-11e7-8dab-6d6ba8a72982",
        "avg": 3.25
      }
    ],
```

What I want is:

```
"ratings": 3.25
```

Any Help would be appreciated.

PS: Laravel 5.2

Comment: Why are you loading all relationships then. you can use `$user_detail=Users::selectRaw('review_user_id, avg(rate) AS avg')->groupBy('review_user_id')->get(); `

Comment: [Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads). Right above you will have __Eager Loading Specific Columns__ - `$users = App\Book::with('author:id,name')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it

```
return $this->hasMany('\App\Reviews','review_user_id','user_id')->
selectRaw('review_user_id, avg(rate) AS avg')->
groupBy('review_user_id')
->pluck('avg');
```

Comment: This won't work - OP has set it up as a relation so it can be eager loaded with `with()`, and a Laravel relationship must return a relationship instance.